# selenium installation firefox gecko drive

Tags: selenium

i have installed all the required jars but i am getting above error for the installation for Firefox browser

```
1504616733589   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
[GPU 7124] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 4448] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 4448] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1504616735505   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1504616735505   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1504616735505   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1504616735510   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\SHIVAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1206861711686569898webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1504616735510   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\SHIVAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1206861711686569898webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1504616735510   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1504616735511   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1504616735511   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1504616735511   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1504616735511   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1504616735512   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping followonsearch@mozilla.com to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\followonsearch@mozilla.com.xpi
1504616735512   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping screenshots@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1504616735512   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org.xpi
1504616735512   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1504616735512   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on aushelper@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1504616735513   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1504616735513   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on e10srollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1504616735513   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1504616735514   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com in app-system-defaults
1504616735514   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1504616735514   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1504616735515   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1504616735515   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1504616735517   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1504616735518   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {}
1504616735938   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/55.0.3/20170824053622/WINNT_x86-msvc-x64/en-US/release/Windows_NT%206.1.1.0%20(x64)/default/default/update.xml
1504616737326   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1504616737870   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1504616737872   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\SHIVAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon
1504616739049   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.1
1504616739050   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org version 55.1
1504616739052   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on screenshots@mozilla.org version 10.12.0
1504616739053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on followonsearch@mozilla.com version 0.9.1
1504616739053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1504616739053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 2.0
1504616739054   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org version 1.2
1504616739054   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
[GPU 7124] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[GPU 7124] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1504616739149   addons.productaddons    WARN    Failed downloading via XHR, status: 0, reason: error
[Child 5372] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 5372] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1504616739304   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1504616739305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1504616739305   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1504616739306   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1504616739307   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1504616739308   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1504616739309   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1504616739309   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1504616739309   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1504616739313   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1504616739321   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
[GPU 7124] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346

###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DW5XQCD007', ip: '10.5.12.110', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: Which version of Geckodriver and which version of Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDriver will support the latest Firefox also, but you have to set the properties for that.

Download "geckodriver.exe" file and download the file [from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\SeleniumAutomation\\geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Change the path of geckodriver.exe in above code as per your system location.

Update your Firefox and Selenium server and client-combined jar.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of firefox are you using. If you're using the latest version, Try uninstalling it and use firefox version 45 or below because the newer versions aren't stable for automation. And you wouldn't even need the gecko driver if you use the older versions.
link to download version 45
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0/win64/en-US/